# How to remove Python 3.8.0 on macOS Catalina 10.15.1? Coz want install Anaconda recommended?

Tags: macos, python, uninstall, anaconda, macos-catalina

I have installed just the python 3.8.0 recently but recommended Anaconda by a friend that better to have because of better support and good in AI ML?

So I want uninstall Python 3.8.0 from Mackbook Air macOS Catalina 10.15.1 how can I do?

I was recommended not to do so, so what are your suggestions are?

Looking forward to hearing from you in your earliest convenience,

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to install and use anaconda without removing the existing python installation. After you have installed anaconda, and you want to create an anaconda virtual environment, you can specify the python version to install by using `conda create --name myenv python=3.7` (or whatever python version you would like)

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda's main advantage is that it (potentially) has more pre-packaged modules available for a variety of platforms versus vanilla Python and `pip` (which downloads modules from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/)). So if you have very specific module requirements for e.g. AI/ML, that might be a benefit.

> I want to uninstall Python 3.8.0 from Mackbook Air with macOS Catalina 10.15.1.

You may want to provide more details in your original question to clarify the exact steps you took to install Python 3.8 then. Otherwise, there are a number of guides available via e.g. Google on this topic.

> I was recommended not to do so, so what are your suggestions?

I would agree with that recommendation. Removing Python installations haphazardly on MacOS can result in your system ceasing to function correctly. The way Anaconda operates, there is no need to remove Python 3.8 from your system. Simply install Anaconda and learn about using Python virtual environments.